# Converting pandas datetime to QuantLib dates: why do the inputs need to be converted to int only some times? It seems random

Tags: programming, quantlib, daycounting

I am trying to use the QuantLib library with Python.

In the example below, I create a pandas dataframe with some dates and some cashflows, convert the dates from pandas' format to QuantLib's, and use QuantLib to calculate the daycount (which is banal for act/365, but QuantLib comes in handy for other cases like 30/360).
There is probably room to make it more efficient (vectorise it somehow?) but it works.

**I then tried to make a function that converts pandas datetime to QuantLib's dates, but it doesn't work, even if the code is the very same!**

```
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Date'.
```

It's the same dataframe apply statement. If, however, I pass `int(x['day'])` instead of just `x['day']` , then it works.

**Why would this be?
pd.DatetimeIndex returns an integer, not a float.
Why does the apply statement not require conversion of the inputs to integer if run outside of a function, but requires it if run within a function? I don't get it!**

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import numpy as np

# I create a dataframe with
# investment in which we pay 100 in the first month, then get 2 each month for the next 59 months

d0 = pd.to_datetime(date(2010,1,1))
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['month #'] = np.arange(0,60)
df['dates'] = df.apply( lambda x: d0 + pd.DateOffset(months = x['month #']) , axis = 1 )
df['cf'] = 0
df.iloc[0,2] = -100
df.iloc[1:,2] = 2

df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dates']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dates']).month
df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['dates']).day

# Now I use pandas apply to add a column which contains the same dates, but in qlib format
df['qldate'] = df.apply( lambda x:   ql.Date(x['day'], x['month'], x['year'] )       , axis = 1)

#now I use qlib to calculate the day count
# NB: actual 365 is easy to calculate manually, but qlib comes in handy for other daycount conventions
# so we don't reinvent the wheel
df['dayc act 365'] = df.apply( lambda x: ql.Actual365Fixed().dayCount(df['qldate'][0], x['qldate'])   , axis =1 )


def date_pd_to_ql(pdate):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pdate).year
    df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pdate).month
    df['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pdate).day
    
    # this works:
    out = df.apply( lambda x: ql.Date(int(x['day']), int(x['month']), int(x['year']) )     , axis = 1  )
    
    # but this doesn't:
    out = df.apply( lambda x: ql.Date(x['day'], x['month'], x['year'] )     , axis = 1  )
    
    return out

out = date_pd_to_ql(df['dates'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use the `ql.Date().from_date` method.

Example:

```
d0 = pd.to_datetime(date(2010,1,1))
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['month #'] = np.arange(0,60)
df['dates'] = df.apply( lambda x: d0 + pd.DateOffset(months = x['month #']) , axis = 1 )
df['cf'] = 0
df.iloc[0,2] = -100
df.iloc[1:,2] = 2

df['qldate'] = df.dates.apply(ql.Date().from_date)
df['dayc act 365'] = df.apply( lambda x: ql.Actual365Fixed().dayCount(df['qldate'][0], x['qldate'])   , axis =1 )

df.head()
```

[image]

Comment: Obrigado! The curiosity of why my code didn't work remains, but yours is of course a much better solution. Do you know if QuantLib for pandas can use numpy arrays or pandas dataframes as inputs? Maybe that's faster than running apply?

Finally, if I may make an observation, I find it is generally better to write df['column'] rather than df.column : the latter causes trouble if the column has the same name as a property of the dataframe, e.g. shape, columns, etc.